# Lite Server hot reload doesn't work for default config

Tags: browser-sync, lite-server, hot-reload

Lite Server doesn't reload the page upon making changes to my index.html file.

I'm not using a bs-config.json file. My index.html opens correctly in a new tab when starting lite server using :

`npm run dev`

This console info might help:

```
> lite@1.0.0 dev C:\test\lite
> lite-server

Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
** browser-sync config **
{ injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.39:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[Browsersync] Watching files...
19.07.26 21:02:27 304 GET /index.html
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

When changing and saving my index.html,

```
[BrowserSync] 'Reloading Browsers'
```

appears in my console, but my page won't reload.
I need to press F5 and then

```
19.07.26 21:09:32 200 GET /index.html
```

appears in my console.

**Package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "lite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.3"
  }
}
```

How do I get Lite Server to hot reload my page ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution

"browser-sync" only works when there is the tag "body"

Just add body tag in your html page

Answer (score 0):

I just rename my code directory without any punctuation characters (. , : ; ! ¡ ? ¿ ‽ & ' " @ \ ¦ • { } ( ) [ ] ° ¨ ‹ › « » … ~). My Lite Server hot reload worked as well